# Vuetify table - add hyperlink to column

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, vue-router

In my vue component I am using vuetify table. It works properly, but I need to make that click on items in column "Category name" redirect to vue view which shows details of clicked item (I need to forward item id to view which shows details of item). I don`t know how to do that?

In method 'editItem' I also need to redirect to other page, with forwarded id, I also don`t know how to do that?

I tried to make "Category name" items as hyperlink, but it does not work and it is without id:

```
<template v-slot:item.categoryName="{ item }">
    <a :href="this.$router.push({name: 'EditCategory'})">{{item.categoryName}}</a>
</template>
```

This is code of my vue component 'CategoryTable':

```
<template>
  <v-data-table
    :headers="headers"
    :items="categories"
    sort-by="categoryName"
    class="elevation-1"
    :footer-props="{
    'items-per-page-options': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
  }"
  :items-per-page="2"
  >
    <template v-slot:top>
      <v-toolbar
        flat
      >
        <v-toolbar-title>Categories Table</v-toolbar-title>
        <v-divider
          class="mx-4"
          inset
          vertical
        ></v-divider>
        <v-spacer></v-spacer>
        <button @click="$router.push({name: 'AddCategory'})">Add category</button>
          </v-toolbar>
    </template>
    <template v-slot:item.actions="{ item }">
      <v-icon
        small
        class="mr-2"
        @click="editItem(item)"
      >
        mdi-pencil
      </v-icon>
      <v-icon
        small
        @click="deleteItem(item)"
      >
        mdi-delete
      </v-icon>
    </template>
  </v-data-table>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
        name: "CategoriesTable",

    data: () => ({
      
      headers: [
        {
          text: 'Category name',
          align: 'start',
          value: 'categoryName',
        },
        { text: 'Description', value: 'description' },
        { text: 'Actions', value: 'actions', sortable: false },
      ],
      categories: [],
      editedIndex: -1,
      defaultItem: {
        id: 0,
        categoryName: '',
        description: '',
      },

    }),

    created () {
      this.initialize()
    },

    methods: {
      initialize () {
      this.$axios.get('/api/categories').then((response) => {
        console.log(response.data)
      this.categories = response.data;
    });
     },

      editItem (item) {
        this.$router.push({name: 'CategoryEdit'});
        item.id

      },

      deleteItem (item) {
      this.$axios.delete('/api/categories/' + item.id).then((response) => {
        console.log(response)
    });
      },
    },
  }
</script>
```

Comment: make whole row, @click="view(item)"

Comment: But it should be click only on Category name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the user to be redirected after clicking on a particular category name, you will pass the corresponding route or id like i did below:

```
<v-data-table
              :headers="headers"
              :items="categories"
              sort-by="categoryName"
              class="elevation-1"
              :footer-props="{
                'items-per-page-options': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
              }"
              :items-per-page="2"
            >
              <template v-slot:item.categoryName="{ item }">
                <a
                 @click="$router.push(`/details/${item.itemID}`)"
                >
                  {{item.categoryName}}
                </a>

              </template>
            </v-data-table>
```

the item id is passed after clicking on the category

Comment: It works, but instead button I should have value of item.categoryName, click on item.categoryName in column 'Category name' should forward me to `/details/${item.itemID}`. Which element that?

Comment: /details/${item.itemID}
is the route where you want to be taken to after clicking

you can change with the appropriate route

Comment: I understant, but instead of button element v-btn (given in your answer) I need to see value of item.categoryName in column 'Category name' (it means text which is item.categoryName) and to click on it. According to your answer I can only see buttons in column 'Category name'. In column 'Category name' I need to see item.categoryName, and there should be possibility to click on item.categoryName.

Comment: OKAY i see, just to replace btn by a tag